Why does "craft" typically designate a small boat if it designates a boat but not a small aircraft/spacecraft if it designates an aircraft/spacecraft?
I read on https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craft:

(plural usually)

a: a boat especially of small size
b
:aircraft
c
:spacecraft


Why does "craft" typically designate a small boat if it designates a boat, but not a small aircraft/spacecraft if it designates an aircraft/spacecraft?

Recall that when the word "aircraft" was coined they were small.

The way meanings of words evolve over time isn't always logical. (The landlord of a pub isn't a nobleman!)

The etymology of "craft" itself is from "ability" or "power" of a person, and the theory is, *The meaning as a mall boat" is recorded by 1670s, probably from a phrase similar to vessels of small craft and referring either to the trade they did or the seamanship they required, or perhaps it preserves the word in its original sense of "power." https://www.etymonline.com/word/craftsman Obviously, the usage has evolved.

There is no special reason for this.  You might note that there is a word "ship" for large boats, but "airship" got taken to mean the aircraft made by Herr Zepplin and others.
But asking "why does a word mean..." is a bit pointless.  "Why are 'bees" called 'bees'?"  You can follow the word back to proto Indo-European "bhei" but that doesn't answer the question.
Similarly you can trace the development of the word "craft" from words meaning "power" or "skill" to the type of boat, to boat-like things in the sky. But you can't say "why" a word means what it means. There is no logic to natural language.

Thanks. Etymology can sometimes give interesting insights.

Yes, it can be interesting, and so motivational, but beware the etymological fallacy. For example "window" comes from "wind eye"  so by the etymological fallacy, "windows" should never have glass!
